# Angled gradient with top offset by specific number of pixels

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a gradient that, for branding purposes, must be (1) at a specific angle, and (2) the top of it must be inset by a specific amount:

[image]

The rest of the proportions don't matter. I created this gradient like this:

`background: linear-gradient(75deg, white 0%, black 30%, blue 30%, white 100%);`

This only produces the correct top inset at specific client area height/widths. At other sizes, offset can be different:

[image]

[image]

Again, for branding reasons, this is unacceptable. That top of that slope must be inset by a specific amount.

I tried use a pixel value for the inset, e.g.

`background: linear-gradient(75deg, white 0%, black 125px, blue 30%, white 100%);`

This works... for the *bottom* of the slope. The bottom will be offset by 125px at any shape/size:

[image]

[image]

I'd like to do the same thing but have the *top* offset fixed to 125px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approximate it using pseudo element and rotation. You consider a straight gradient (`90deg`) then you rotate it by adjusting the `transform-origin` to have the distance you want on the top:

```css
.box {
   height:300px;
   position:relative;
   overflow:hidden;
}
.box:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  /* a random big value for top bottom and left*/
  top:-500px;
  bottom:-500px;
  right:0;
  left:-500px;
  /**/
  /* in the below 625px = 125px + 500px and adjust the 350px to get close to the gradient you wnat*/
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, white 350px , black 625px, blue 0, white);
  transform:rotate(-15deg);
  transform-origin:625px 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```